# Having problem with IncreaseItem function

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native

My result is seeing `item.acf.count` as `string` and not as `number`. How can I convert this to number?

Here is the function below.

```
increaseItem = (id) => {
    const { cart } = this.state;
    cart.forEach(item => {
        if (item.id === id) {
            item.acf.count += 1
                
        }
    })
    this.setState({
        cart:cart
    })
}
```

Comment: You can use parseInt(int) to parse a string to Int, or parseFloat(float) to parse a string to float

Comment: parseInt is not soultion but hot fix, you should find a place where you inited "cart" and there change string type to number type, if u cant figure it out show us your STATE definition

Answer (score 0):

> My result is seeing item.acf.count as string and not as number. please
> how can I convert is to number

You should ensure that the initial `item.acf.count` state is a number type so this `count: item.acf.count + 1` operation works correctly and returns a number type. So long as your state updaters maintain the state invariant of `item.acf.count` being a number it should work as expected.

Additionally, the `increaseItem` handler is mutating the cart state and not creating new array/object references.

```
increaseItem = (id) => {
  const { cart } = this.state; // <-- cart is reference to cart state
  cart.forEach(item => {
    if (item.id === id) {
      item.acf.count += 1; // <-- mutation!
    }
  });
  this.setState({
    cart: cart // <-- cart state reference back into state
  })
}
```

You should instead shallow copy the cart and then also shallow copy the cart item (*any any other nested properties*) you want to update. I also suggest using a functional state update so you are correctly updating from the previous state and not any state value closed over in `increaseItem` callback scope.

```
increaseItem = (id) => {
  this.setState(prevState => ({
    cart: prevState.cart.map(item => item.id === id
      ? {
        ...item,
        acf: {
          ...item.acf,
          count: item.acf.count + 1
        }
      }
      : item),
  }));
}
```